# In school and trying to create the classic guess a number game. What did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript

This code is supposed to be a guess the number game. The object is to get JS to display an alert box that asks the user to guess a number. When they guess a number, the code is supposed to return the values of what they have guessed until they get it correct.

When I run the play key, an alert box does pop up, and says:

```
"Enter a guess between 1 and 100"
```

After that, even if I enter all 100 numbers, the box re-loads forever.

Here's what I have:

```
const game = {
  title: 'Guess the Number!',
  biggestNum: 100,
  smallestNum: 1,
  playerChoice: null,
  secretNum: null,
  //1. Add a prevGuesses property to the game object initialized to an empty array.
  prevGuesses: [],
  //2. Add a getGuess method to game that prompts the player to enter a guess with a message formatted as: Enter a guess between [smallestNum] and [biggestNum]: Hint- Use a template literal for the prompt message.

  //3. Ensure that the getGuess method returns a value that is:
  //-is a number, not a string
  // -is between smallestNum and biggestNum, inclusive
  // -Hints: This is a great use case for a while loop. parseInt returns NaN if the string cannot be parsed into a number
  getGuess: function() {
    while (this.playerChoice !== this.secretNum) {
   var playerChoice = prompt(`Enter a guess between ${this.smallestNum} and ${this.biggestNum}: `);
    var wholeNumber = parseInt(this.playerChoice);
    if (this.wholeNumber > this.biggestNum) {
      var wholeNumber = 100;
    } 
    if (this.wholeNumber < this.smallestNum) {
     var wholeNumber = 1;
    }
    if (typeof this.wholeNumber !== "number")) {
      var wholeNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    }
   } 
  },
//4. From within the play method, invoke the getGuess method and add the new guess to the prevGuesses array
    play: function() {
    this.secretNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 
      (this.biggestNum - this.smallestNum + 1)) + this.smallestNum;
      game.getGuess();
     this.prevGuesses.push(this.wholeNumber);
        //6 the play method should end(return) when the guess matches the secretNum
      if (typeof(this.wholeNumber) === "number" && this.wholeNumber !== this.secretNum) {
        game.render();
      }
   
      
  },
  // 5. Add a render method to game that play will call after a guess has been made that alerts:
// -if the secret has been guessed: "Congrats! you guessed the number in [x] guesses!"

// otherwise

// -"Your guess is too [high|low]"
// "Previous guesses: x, x, x, x"

// Hints: render wont be able to access any of play's local variables, e.g., guess, so be sure to pass render any arguments as needed. Template literals not only have interpolation, they honor whitespace - including line breaks! The list of previous guesses can be generated using the array join method.
    render: function() {
      if (this.wholeNumber === secretNum) {
          alert(`Congrats! You guessed the number in ${game.prevGuesses.length} guesses!
          Previous guesses: ${prevGuesses}`);
      } else if (this.wholeNumber > this.secretNum) {
          alert(`Your guess is too high!
          Previous guesses: ${this.prevGuesses}`);
          game.guess();
      } else if (this.wholeNumber < this.secretNum) {
          alert(`Your guess is too low!
          Previous guesses: ${this.prevGuesses}`);
          game.guess();
      }
    }
  
};


game.play();
/*
Allow the player to continually be prompted to enter their guess of what the secret number is until they guess correctly
If the player has an incorrect guess, display an alert message that informs the player:

Whether their guess is too high, or too low, and...
A list of all the previously guessed numbers (without showing the square brackets of an array)
If the player has guessed the secret number:

Display an alert message that congrats the player and informs them of how many guesses they took
End the game play*/

/*


Bonus: when play is run, immediately prompt the player to enter the smallest and biggest numbers instead of having them pre-set*/
```

The research that I've done: I've googled as many pages as I could find and youtube tutorials on functions, play object, loops within arrays, anything that I could think of that's related to the types of objects in this code.

the comment text is from the assignment. While I was working on it, I put the comments next to the code that I was working on.

I really am only a few weeks into coding and appreciate any feedback.

This is the original code that I was provided:

```
const game = {
  title: 'Guess the Number!',
  biggestNum: 100,
  smallestNum: 1,
  secretNum: null,
  play: function() {
    this.secretNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 
      (this.biggestNum - this.smallestNum + 1)) + this.smallestNum;
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I updated to post to add more information and provide more clarity. I'm in school and really just trying not to fail one of my first assignments. I have asked other people for help as well and this is just as far as I keep getting.

Comment: You are logging a reference to a function object to the console. To actually call the function, use `game.play()`. (Note parentheses)

Comment: okay. You're right. I apologize. I guess I let my panic get the best of me. I'll do better to be better. I appreciate the labor you've invested to give me feedback. I'll use it to continue to enhance the quality of this post and be a better advocate for myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- `this.wholeNumber` never receives a value, so that will not work. Also, it does not seem the purpose of this exercise to have such a property. You should not have to store the user's guess in a new property `this.wholeNumber`. See next point:
- The goal of `getGuess` is to *return* a number, but there is no `return` statement. You seem to want to store the number in a property, but that is not the assignment.
- Related to this: in `play` you should get the guessed number as a return value from the call to `getGuess`
- The goal of `getGuess` is not to wait for the user to guess right, only for the user to make a *valid* guess (within range and not `NaN`). So the condition of your `while` loop is not correct.
- `getGuess` does not verify that `parseInt` returned `NaN`. Note that the type of `NaN` is "number", so the last `if`'s condition will never be true. You should use the `isNaN` function, or better `Number.isNaN`.
- `play` should *always* call `render`, not only when the guess is right.
- `render` should be called by passing it an argument (the guessed number), and thus the `render` method should define a parameter for it.
- The `render` method should *not* call `game.guess()`. That is not its job.
- The `play` method should not put a new value in `secret`, otherwise the user will be playing against a moving target :) The `secret` should be set once in the main program
- The main program -- where you currently just have `game.play()` -- should have the looping logic, which you had tried to implement elsewhere. Here is where you should repeat calling `game.play()` until the guess is right. It is also here where you should display alert messages about guesses that are too low, too high, ...etc.
- There is no clear instruction where the main program should get the latest guess from. It can get it from `game.prevGuesses`, but I would suggest that the `play` method also *returns* the latest guess, just like `getGuess` should do.
- Take note of the other instructions that are given in comments for the main program. For instance, when the user has guessed right you should alert after how many attempts they got it right. Think of which property can help you to know this number of attempts. Hint: `length`.

I will not provide the corrected code here, as I think with the above points you have enough material to bring this exercise to a good end. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses to invoke the play function.

```
game.play();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply!!When I run it that way it gives me a weird error message.


ReferenceError: number is not defined
    at Object.play (/script.js:37:40)
    at /script.js:70:6

Comment: it's saying that number is not defined at object play

Comment: You never defined `this.wholeNumber`. You'll need to restructure your code.

Comment: And `typeof(this.wholeNumber) === number` should be `typeof(this.wholeNumber) === "number"`. That's what is causing the error, but you'll need to change up your code anyway.

Comment: I was trying to set it so that as long as the variable returned as any number, the if statement would execute. I guess I thought that I could set it === number, but I guess it just thinks its a variable. Your question helped me work through that. Now I need to re-evaluate that if statement

Comment: thanks for that. I know I have a lot of work to do to make it functional. This helps a lot

Comment: @RonaldCross Happy to help.